# parse iptables logs with regex

Tags: regex, iptables

i have a bellow  log of iptables access running on centos 7 server.

```
Aug 13 17:16:33 app-srv01 kernel: newConnection - IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=56:00:01:a1:5c:b7:fe:00:01:a1:5c:b7:08:00 SRC=91.103.125.80 DST=45.33.223.166 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=21200 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=55743 DPT=445 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Using this regex `([^ ]+)=([^ ]+)` i can parse everthing after IN string, but i need to the beginner content like `Aug 13 17:16:33` `app-srv01` `newConnection` more `([^ ]+)=([^ ]+)`

Some can help me complete this regex please.

Thanks

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve in the end?

Comment: Hi i need parse the date hour and all text after between kernel: and IN tag.
Because the rest of line this regex do it `([^ ]+)=([^ ]+)`
Look this: https://imgur.com/a/LJzjmIN
thanks

Comment: some can help me :/

Comment: `^[^ ]+|[^ ]+.` this will split your log into groups of entries.. Not sure if it's any help. You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/sb7dLJ/1

Comment: @BogdanStoica thnks boy in regex101 works, i will try on my pyton application /o/

Comment: I've added an answer to this question as well. If that's what you were looking for, please don't forget to mark the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to take any entry from the log and split in groups, as in, each entry will be one group and so on. The regex for that would be:

`^[^ ]+|[^ ]+.` You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/sb7dLJ/1

Please keep in mind that the regex above is pcre (php) regex. I'm not sure if the exact same regex will actually work in python since as far as I know, python regex syntax is different.

Not sure why you needed that regex from the start if you wanted to use it in python. In python you could use something like this:

**Python 2.7.10** (it will work with any python 2.7.x version and 3.x as well)

```
>>> logline = 'Aug 13 17:16:33 app-srv01 kernel: newConnection - IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=56:00:01:a1:5c:b7:fe:00:01:a1:5c:b7:08:00 SRC=91.103.125.80 DST=45.33.223.166 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=21200 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=55743 DPT=445 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0'

>>> logline.split(' ')[0:25]

['Aug', '13', '17:16:33', 'app-srv01', 'kernel:', 'newConnection', '-', 'IN=eth0', 'OUT=', 'MAC=56:00:01:a1:5c:b7:fe:00:01:a1:5c:b7:08:00', 'SRC=91.103.125.80', 'DST=45.33.223.166', 'LEN=52', 'TOS=0x00', 'PREC=0x00', 'TTL=113', 'ID=21200', 'DF', 'PROTO=TCP', 'SPT=55743', 'DPT=445', 'WINDOW=8192', 'RES=0x00', 'SYN', 'URGP=0']
>>>
```

Not sure if that's what you were looking for though...